# How to group ints by the number of digits with LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Basically I have a number of ints let's say 20 from the range of 0-100 and I want to group them by the number of digits(1 digit, 2 digits, and 3 digits). 
It should be in ascending order which applies to groups and also the numbers in those groups.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 100, 5, 88, 6, 45, 12, 34, 11, 6, 17, 35, 55, 54, 34, 7, 12, 33, 2, 41, 5 };
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far and why isn't that working for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can get their length by converting them to string then group them

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 100, 5, 88, 6, 45, 12, 34, 11, 6, 17, 35, 55, 54, 34, 7, 12, 33, 2, 41, 5 };

var ndigitsList = numbers.GroupBy(c => c.ToString().Length)
                         .Select(c => c.ToList().OrderBy(num => num))
                         .ToList();

ndigitsList .ForEach(numslist =>
 {
    Console.WriteLine(numslist.First().ToString().Length + ":");
    numslist.ToList().ForEach(num =>
    {
    Console.WriteLine(num);
    });
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
 });
//output
//3 : 100
//1 : 2 5 5 6 7 ...
//2 : 11 12 12 17 ...
```

if you have Negative values then you have to use absolute value.

```
var ndigitsList = numbers.GroupBy(c => Math.Abs(c).ToString().Length)
                         .Select(c => c.ToList().OrderBy(num => num)).ToList();
```

Comment: A comment that has since been deleted indicated that this solution would "fail" with negative numbers. Well, it would not "fail', but it would indeed provide an incorrect result. The OP stipulated that the range of numbers was between "0-100"...so no negative numbers. However, a simple change would allow negative numbers as well:: `Math.Abs(c).ToString().Length`

Comment: @Barns yes it was a nice catch, I was updating my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, also i have no idea how to output those numbers. Any sugestions?

Comment: @Frontmaniaac just update my answer, Happy to help